# How do I create a column that contains a nested array in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I've been trying to do the following but it am not sure how to achieve this result in pyspark 2.4.

I have a nested array, and I want to create a new column that uses this existing nested array as it's default value.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("NestedArrayColumn").getOrCreate()

# Define the dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)], ["col1"])

# Define the nested array
nested_array = [["string1", "string2"], ["string3", "string4"], ["string4", "string1"]]

# Create a new column in the dataframe
df = df.withColumn("new_col", lit(nested_array))  #this does not work for me. I am limited to pyspark 2.4 as well so my options are limited.

# Desired output

+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col1|                                                                 new_col|
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1|[["string1", "string2"], ["string3", "string4"], ["string4", "string1"]]|
|   2|[["string1", "string2"], ["string3", "string4"], ["string4", "string1"]]|
|   3|[["string1", "string2"], ["string3", "string4"], ["string4", "string1"]]|
|   4|[["string1", "string2"], ["string3", "string4"], ["string4", "string1"]]|
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

nested_array = [["string1", "string2"], ["string3", "string4"], ["string4", "string1"]]
nested_array = [F.array(*map(F.lit, x)) for x in nested_array]
df = df.withColumn('new_col', F.array(nested_array))
```

`map` is from the Python built-in function and many Pyspark function names conflict with built-in functions, so I tend to make a namespace for Pyspark functions as `F`.